# Modifying Table Columns

Tags: angularjs

How can I reduce the width of the day columns ("MON", "TUES", etc.) to match the space required for "MON" or "TUES, etc.? In other words, I'd like to set the width of the day columns equal to the length of the column's title.

http://jsfiddle.net/BnLEh/

```
<div ng-app="MyModule">
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <table border='1' width='200'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td ng-repeat='day in days' width='20%'>{{day}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat='x in [1,2,3,4]'>
            <td>
                <input placeholder='Enter Charge #' size='10'>
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat='t in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]' width='10%'>
                <input type="number" size='3'>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
 </div>
```

.

```
var optModule = angular.module('MyModule', []);

    function Controller($scope) {   
        $scope.days = ["", "MON", "TUE", "WED", 
            "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"];        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the input width to inherit from its parent by setting its width to 100%

```
<input style="width: 100%" type="number" size='3'>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BnLEh/10/

[textboxes in HTML table: How to auto-size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190550/textboxes-in-html-table-how-to-auto-size)